# Android - Change position and size of gallery?

Tags: android

I have a gallery in my app, is there a way change the position of it?

I tried `android:gravity="center"` but that did nothing. Cant get the gallery to move.

Also can the gallery be made bigger? By an exact size too? I don't want it to be fullscreen but i do want it to be bigger than it normally is. Close to fullscreen. Nothing i've done has changed it.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `layout_width` and `layout_height` to set the size, the Gallery can be made to be pretty much any size you like. Usually you'll chose `wrap_contents` or `fill_parent`, but if you want to you can explicitly set the height to something such as 400dp and the width you would probably want to keep `fill_parent`. See [declaring layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#layout-params) in Android docs for more info.

EDIT: Here is an example in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:spacing="2px"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, i've already tried fill_parent and wrap_content to no use. I need an exact size. Android dev pages are sending me in circles and i cant make heads of tails of certain things. I was told that this bit of code would work: Gallery mGallery = new Gallery();  
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(); 
params.height = 150; 
params.width = 150; 
mGallery.setLayoutParams(params); but i have no idea how to implement it. All i know is the code goes in the class, but nothing else.

Comment: You can do this either from code or using XML. It sounds like you are having trouble attaching the layout to your Activity. In your onCreate method call setContentView with either the id of the XML layout or pass the View that you created. For example setContentView(mGallery); or setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

Comment: Did a bit more searching through my code and i found the layoutparams already in there so all i had to do was edit the numbers to increase the gallery size. So simple, cannot believe i missed it. Thanks for your help.